# Define whether a device supports video format

Tags: android

I need to define if a device can play a video file. So far, I've registered [an error handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnErrorListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener%29) which receives a number of errors which might be tolerable - I mean even though they occur player still feels fine and keeps on working.

However, I need somehow to distinguish between errors that are unimportant and those that are related to MediaPlayer's inability to play certain video formats. Or there's another way of defining whether video can be played ?

Maybe there's a functionality to extract all supportable types of videos and compare them to a video type that is being played ?

Thanks.

Comment: you can't determine that. a) you don't know the encoding of a file, just the extension tells you nothing about that. b) even if you know the encoding details there is nothing that can tell you if that file really fits the capabilities of the decoder. Some can play e.g. WMV some can't and if a device can it still depends on several factors like video bitrate < max supported bitrate. A strong hint that the file is playable is when it is indexed as Video in MediaStore.

Answer (score 0):

If by types you mean extensions, so this can be helpful:
[Android Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

EDIT: You can compare the formats by creating any collection that will contain the supported formats, and then check the format of the file, and check if it is contained in the collection.

Here's an example of a method that extract file format:

```
private String getFileExtention(String fileName) {
      String ext="";
      int mid= fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
      ext=fileName.substring(mid+1,fileName.length());  
      return ext;
}
```

Comment: Yes and I've been there. I need a way of extracting currently supported types and a type of the video being played - is it possible ? so that I can decide what to do in case it can't.

Comment: thanks, but this code - simply get an extension without comparing - it's not enough. Besides, I think zapl is right, so I have to find another way

Answer (score 0):

There is a hidden api android.media.Mediafile.isMimeTypeMedia. You could use a reflection on it to get whether your mime type is supported.
The function signature is

```
 public static boolean isMimeTypeMedia(String mimeType)
```

in the Mediafile class with package android.media.